# Updating Email templates and Email Send activities in Journeys

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Documentation is not clear.  Can someone validate the order of operations to publish (and validate) Email template updates in active Journeys?

- Update content in Email Templates
- Navigate to running Journeys with said Email Templates
- Click into applicable Email send Activity object
- Choose Activity Summary from drop down arrow
- In the Activity Summary view, click Done -- Popup window with "Saving" appears

To validate, you can send yourself an Email preview or navigate to Email Studio > Interactions > Triggered Emails > Journey Builder Sends.  Confirm publish date for Journey version is today's date.

Comment: Those are the correct steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this help doc from Salesforce which I have followed to edit Journey Builder sends and its worked perfectly.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_update_an_email_in_a_running_journey.htm&type=5

1. Click the Email Activity on the Journey Canvas.
2. Click the side bar and select Activity Summary.
3. Click Edit and make your changes.
4. Click Done.

NOTE When updating AMPScript in an email that is used in a running journey, pause and republish its associated triggered send.